# how to create a list of type obtained from reflection

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, reflection, wpfdatagrid

I have a code which looks like this :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ReflectionTest.dll");
Type myType = assembly.GetType(@"ReflectionTest.TestObject");
var x = Convert.ChangeType((object)t, myType);   

//List<myType> myList = new List<myType>();
//myList.Add(x);
```

The commented part of the code is where I am stuck. I am getting some objects from a service and the conversion works fine too. I am trying to populate a list of such objects and will later bind to WPF DataGrid.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myType)
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

var addMethod = listType.GetMethod("Add");
addMethod.Invoke(list, new object[] { x });
```

You might be able to cast to `IList` and call `Add` directly instead of looking up the method with reflection:

```
var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
list.Add(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>);
var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(myType);

var myList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
myList.Add(x);
```

The list will not be strongly-typed but you can add items as objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.generictypeparameterbuilder.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var argument = new Type[] { typeof(myType) };
var listType = typeof(List<>); 
var genericType = listType.MakeGenericType(argument); // create generic type
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);  // create generic List instance

var method = listType.GetMethod("Add"); // get Add method
method.Invoke(instance, new [] { argument }); // invoke add method
```

Alternatively you can cast your instance to `IList` and directly use `Add` method.Or use `dynamic` typing and don't worry about casting:

```
dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
list.Add("bla bla bla...");
```