# How to create a mutable list with a type retrieved via reflections

Tags: generics, kotlin, reflection, generic-collections

I am currently working on a deserialization problem which requires the population of a mutable list in kotlin with a generic type obtained via reflections. Specifically, I am provided with a function variable, and I need to make the mutable list's generic type equal to the return type of that function.

While I can return a MutableList of type "Any", under the hood I need it to have a specific type -- I've tried something like below but that doesn't work. I've found a very similar problem on stackoverflow solved here, but I am having trouble converting it to kotlin: [how to create a list of type obtained from reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513382/how-to-create-a-list-of-type-obtained-from-reflection)

```
val jsonArray = jsonTree.get("arrayFieldName") // returns jsonNode
val method: Method = retrieveMethod() // JsonNode::intValue / booleanValue / ...

val genericList = mutableListOf<method.returnType>()
for (item in jsonArray.elements())
  genericList.add(method.invoke(item))

return genericList
```

Comment: Unlike C#, in Kotlin and Java, generic types are all essentially compiled to `Any?`. This is called type erasure and makes generic types useless for types acquired by reflection. Maybe you can share the use case that makes `<Any>` not work for you so we can get to the root of the issue.

Comment: What is the return type of the method the `return genericList` belongs to? How do you ensure that it is compatible to the return type of the reflection `Method`?