# Reflection: Dynamically get type and use to create a List (error: is a variable but is used like a type)

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

```
public class Worker<T>
{
  public void Work(T expected)
  {
     // Get a list of all the properties that the incoming object owns
     PropertyInfo[] objectProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

     // Grab the first property
     PropertyInfo property = objectProperties [0];

     // Get the property's type
     string propertyType = property.PropertyType.Name;

     // If this item is a list, then lets recreate the list
     if(propertyType.StartsWith("List"))
     {
       Type listType= a[0].GetType();
       List<listType> myList = new List<listType>();
     }
  }
}
```

In the code above, the following line is wrong:

```
List<listType> myList = new List<listType>();
```

How do I dynamically create a list using reflection?

I am getting the error message,

> " 'listType' is a variable but is used like a type "

Comment: @thehennyy, How would I use this for a List object? I have looked for around a lot in Stack Overflow for the answer but cannot piece together what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listType)`

Comment: @madreflection, thanks for the help. if you put this as the answer i'll mark as the answer

Comment: This question gets asked a lot. I know there's a better duplicate out there. Having trouble finding it for some reason.

Comment: You can hide question if you want but the answer you gave isn't listed in the mentioned StackOverflow post. You use MakeGenericType whereas the mentioned post uses MakeGenericMethod. It would have taken me longer to figure this out without your help. (okay, Thanks again for the help).

Comment: A better duplicate: [how to create a list of type obtained from reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21513409)